# Watch contract events without heaving to set up na api key or MetaMask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, events, infura

I really just need to listen for events coming from the smart contract. Metamask works good on pc but it wont work on mobile and other circumstances. I was thinkng about an open api from infura but still I'm not sure it allows events watching. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infura doesn't allow filter creation over HHTTPProvider, but it does by WebSocket, which is, in fact, faster than HTTP. So you can use web3 and infura to create a webpage that watches events, this will run on any platform.

Hope this helps

Comment: is the api key needed for just reading events?

Comment: Yes, but the only thing you need to do is to fill a form (it is free), if you do not want to identify your personal email just create quickly a new one and register that one.

Comment: for the websocket API a key is not needed: https://infura.io/docs/wss/introduction